# NDSolve with shooting method

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics, nonlinear

Here are my equations:

```
eq1 = f'''[t] + (f[t] + g[t])*f''[t] - (f'[t])^2 == 0;
eq2 = g'''[t] + (f[t] + g[t])*g''[t] - (g'[t])^2 == 0;
eq3 = θ''[t] + (f[t] + g[t])*.7*θ'[t] == 0;    ic1 = f[0] == s;
ic2 = g[0] == 0;
ic3 = f'[0] == λ;
ic4 = g'[0] == λ1;
ic5 = θ[0] == 1;
ic6 = f'[η] == 0;
ic7 = g'[η] == 0;
ic8 = θ[η] == 0; 
equations = {eq1, eq2, eq3};
initialconditions = {ic1, ic2, ic3, ic4, ic5, ic6, ic7, ic8};
```

and the solution method:

```
s4 = Table[{λ, f''[0] /.  NDSolve[Join[equations,          
    initialconditions /. {λ1 -> -0.5, η -> 5, s -> 4}], {f'', g', θ}, {t, 0, 20},
    Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> {f[0] == 4, f'[0] == -1, 
    f''[0] == 20, g[0] == 0, g'[0] == -0.5, g''[0] == 0, θ[0] == 1, 
    θ'[0] == 0}}][[1]]}, {λ, -3.70, 0, 0.01}];    
s42 = Table[{λ, f''[0] /. NDSolve[Join[equations, 
    initialconditions /. {λ1 -> -0.5, η -> 20, s -> 4}], {f'', g, θ}, {t, 0, 20}][[1]]}, 
    {λ, -3.70, 0, 0.1}]

ListPlot[{s4, s42}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, {Red, Dashed}, Purple, {Purple, Dashed}, 
   Cyan, {Cyan, Dashed}}, Joined -> True, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style ["\[Lambda]", 20], Style["f''(0)", 18]}, 
 AspectRatio -> .7, PlotRange -> All]
```

**and I get the following results:**

[image]

**how can I remove the noises to get the following results?**
[image]

Comment: It takes forever on my machine to execute `s4`. I don't why.

Comment: It takes about 2 minute to solve. you can change {-3.7,0,0.01} to {-3.7,0,0.1} to speedup

Comment: why are you not using the shooting method for the problematic solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The second curve is irregular, because the `s42` calculation yields the desired second solution for some values of `λ` and the first solution for others.  To obtain only the desired second solution, use

```
s42 = Table[{λ, f''[0] /. NDSolve[{equations, 
    initialconditions /. {λ1 -> -0.5, η -> 20, s -> 4}}, {f'', g', θ}, {t, 0, 20},
    Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> {f[0] == 4, f'[0] == -1, 
    f''[0] == .6 λ^2 - 6, g[0] == 0, g'[0] == -0.5, g''[0] == 1.6, θ[0] == 1,
    θ'[0] == -2.1}}][[1]]}, {λ, -3.70, 0, 0.1}]
```

[image]

The challenge, of course, is to provide `"StartingInitialConditions"` for `f''[0]`, `g''[0]`, and `θ'[0]`.  A bit of experimentation led to the `f''[0]` expression, while the second and third were obtained by computing their more or less constant values from the second solution for `λ < -2.5`.

Note that in the Question `η -> 5` for `s4`, and `η -> 20` for `s42`.  Probably, the values should be the same for meaningful comparison.  Also, computing `s4` is exceedingly slow due to its `0.01` step size.  Instead, I used this small step size only for `-3.7 < λ < -3.5`, and `0.1` otherwise.  Finally, it is not necessary to use `Join`.

Comment: Can you share the modified code. Pl.
subhrasmitamohanty98@gmail.com

Comment: @smohanty To what modified code are you referring?