# Dual solution of nonlinear ordinary differential equations

Tags: differential-equations, fluid-dynamics

As we know, we can solve nonlinear ordinary differential equations arising in fluid dynamics using Mathematica command `NDsolve`. But, now I want to find the dual solution of the following nonlinear ordinary differential equations

$$(1-n)f{'''} -(f')^2 +f{''} f+nW_ef{'''}{(f'')}-M^2 f{'}=0,$$
$$\theta{''} + Pr \left(f\theta{'} +Q\theta \right)=0,$$

with boundary conditions

$$f(0)=0,\ f'(0)= 1 + \alpha f{''} (0), \ \theta=1+b\ \theta'(0),$$
$$f'\rightarrow 0,\ \theta\rightarrow 0\ \text{as} \ \eta\rightarrow \infty,$$

using Mathematica. Is there any built-in function or code to find dual solutions for such problems?

Comment: Please share the code in copyable form, so that other users can play with it. No one wants to retype all this code (and double check for correct transition).

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is a dual solution?  Do you have a good introductory reference to link to?

Comment: Maybe you mean the solution of an "adjoint equation" that arises in optimal flow control problems? Please, be more precise.

Comment: I guess, the OP meant to say that $f$ and $\theta$ has two solution curves each. For a particular set of parameters, there could be two different solutions to the given system.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NDSolve with shooting method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/84661/ndsolve-with-shooting-method)

Answer (score 2):

**Comment**

(I am leaving this as comment because maybe someone would come up with a better way to handle such problems.)

To the best of my [info](https://www.google.co.uk/search?ei=ChE_W_X_B8STgAbwh6JY&q=fluid%20flow%20dual%20solutions%20&oq=fluid%20flow%20dual%20solutions%20&gs_l=psy-ab.3...51618.55828.0.56672.4.4.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..4.0.0....0.9OZpLTE9yII), dual solutions exists in the case of flow over stretching/shrinking sheet. To account for this, I changed the boundary condition `f'[0] == 1 + alpha*f''[0]` to `f'[0] == \[Lambda] + alpha*f''[0]`, where `\[Lambda]` is the stretching/shrinking parameter.

Here is my try which lots of warnings but still you can see the dual solutions.

```
eq1 = (1 - n)*f'''[t] + f[t]*f''[t] - (f'[t])^2 + n*We*f'''[t]*f''[t] - M^2*f'[t] == 0;

eq2 = \[Theta]''[t] + Pr*(f[t]*\[Theta]'[t] + Q*\[Theta][t]) == 0;

ic1 = f[0] == 0;

ic2 = f'[0] == \[Lambda] + alpha*f''[0];

ic3 = \[Theta][0] == 1 + b*\[Theta]'[0];

ic4 = f'[\[Eta]] == 0;

ic5 = \[Theta][\[Eta]] == 0;

eqns = {eq1, eq2};

ics = {ic1, ic2, ic3, ic4, ic5};

sys = Join[eqns, ics] /. {n -> 0.2, \[Eta] -> 5, alpha -> 0.2, We -> 0.1, M -> 0.5, Q -> 0.1, Pr -> 0.7, b -> 0.5};

s1 = Table[{\[Lambda], f''[0] /. NDSolve[sys, {f'', \[Theta]}, {t, 0, 5}, 
       Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> {f[0] == 0, f'[0] == -0.1, 
           f''[0] == 1, \[Theta][0] == 1, \[Theta]'[0] == 0}}][[1]]}, {\[Lambda], -0.3, 0, 0.02}];

s2 = Table[{\[Lambda], f''[0] /. NDSolve[sys, {f'', \[Theta]}, {t, 0, 5}, 
       Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> {f[0] == 0, f'[0] == -0.1, 
           f''[0] == .6 \[Lambda]^2 - 6, \[Theta][0] == 
            1, \[Theta]'[0] == -2.1}}][[1]]}, {\[Lambda], -0.3, 0, 0.02}];

ListLinePlot[{s1, s2}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]